# Select multiple rows with MAX value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Given this table:

```
players(id,team,name,age)
```

I want to select the oldest player/s for each team

My query so far:

```
select p.team,p.name,MAX(p.age)
from players p
group by p.team
```

This query gives me the oldest player for each team but if there are multiple players with the same MAX age it selects only one of those at random.
How can I make it so it selects all of them?

Comment: You should tag your database. For many databases this query is invalid (and as a bug not accepted as invalid in some). Answer to your question might be something like "with ties" if it were MS SQL Server (but in MS SQL this query is invalid). You should remove p.name from the result list to start with.

Comment: @Cetin Basoz I used an online tool for queries using MySQL 5.6

Comment: I have added the MySQL tag

Comment: That online tool is creating invalid queries then. Don't use IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query:

```
select p.team, p.name, MAX(p.age)
from players p
group by p.team;
```

Should return a syntax error.  The `group by` clause is inconsistent with the `select`, because `p.name` is not in the `group by` and not the argument to an aggregation function.

To do what you want, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select p.*
from players p
where p.age = (select max(p2.age) from players p2 where p2.team = p.team);
```

Comment: Thanks! If I understood it well for every row of p  it is checked if the age  is equal to the result of a query on another copy of the table where only the rows in which the value of team corresponds with the one in p are considered.

Comment: @Mizzet . . . Yes, you understand that well.